# How to validate session ID if I know the session ID in Apache Shiro without the use of any hash maps?

Tags: apache, validation, session, shiro

I know that the session ID can be validated using hashmap and attaching it to a listener. Also there was a deprecated method to validate using only the session ID string.

I want to know is there an alternative way to validate the known session ID in Apache Shiro without the use of any hashmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution would be to create the subject using the passed session ID and then trying to get the session of that subject. If a session exist then it will return its `session` else `null`. For example, below method can be used to validate an Apache Shiro's session using a passed session ID.

```
 public static boolean isSessionValid(String sessionId){  
      Subject requestedSubject = new Subject.Builder().sessionId(sessionId).buildSubject();
      return !(requestedSubject.getSession(false) == null);
  }
```

Comment: why I always get the exception: `SessionKey must be an HTTP compatible implementation`. According to debug, I find that if we only put the `sessionId` in the builder, it will create `DefaultSessionKey`, which is not HTTP compatible, so `WebUtils.isHttp(key) `will return false, and the exception will throw.

Comment: @Utkal Sinha I am also trying the same. I have the SESSION ID in my cookie. I am passing the session ID to validate. I am getting below error `{
"URL": "http://gui_backend/edennet/commanding/session/F996B1458D66427FC36877BB2FEC87C9",
"exceptionClass": "class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
"RESTMethod": "GET",
"message": "SessionKey must be an HTTP compatible implementation.",
"rootCausePointClass": "org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.ServletContainerSessionManager",
"rootCausePointMethod": "getSession"
}`